# Establishing Concurrency of the "same" process in linux - Curl

Tags: php, linux, curl, concurrency

How can one achieve true concurrency of processes in linux. I am trying to establish as many connections as possible from a linux client using simple curl command. For this, I want to invoke 1000 curl to the same destination URL and measure the time taken for each request.

What is the best way to do this? Also what is the best way to verify that 1000 requests are created at the same time (Spawning 1000 processes?).

I tried to use xargs as below:

```
seq 1 1000 | xargs -n1 -P1000 bash -c 'curl <url>'
```

The URL it fetches is in the order of a few KBs, within the network cards capabilities altogether. However, they tend to be fast enough that I cannot make sure if all connections were concurrent and if it spawned 1000 processes at the same time.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: check out the [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) command it allows you to specify the number of connections and how many are concurrent.

Comment: Thanks Orangepill for the suggestion. AB is good, but I want to also extend this to use other tools than curl, like my custom app.

Comment: You should look at the GNU parallel project. It accepts a "-j1000" parameter and the command you wish to run in bulk. You can then count the active spawned curl requests using a quick grep of your process list.